# Google Maps API - Calculate Zoom based of Miles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How would one calculate the zoom of a map, based on miles input is given?

An example would be that the user selects from a drop-down that they want to search within a 50 miles radius. The map zoom level should update to show 50 miles area around the original coordinates given in the map.

My attempt which is as inaccurate and amature as it can be...

```
calculateZoomLevel(miles) {
    let zoom = 11;

    switch(miles) {
        case 5 : {
            zoom = 14;
            break;
        }
        case 15 : {
            zoom = 13;
            break;
        }
        case 25 : {
            zoom = 11;
            break;
        }
        case 50 : {
            zoom = 10;
            break;
        }
        case 100 : {
            zoom = 8;
            break;
        }
        case 3963.2 : {
            zoom = 1
        }
    }

    return zoom;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean calculate the zoom of a map based on an input of miles? Can you give an example scenario?

Comment: @rmlan just added an example

Comment: Why did i get a downvote without any feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest option is to create a `google.maps.Circle` object with your desired radius, then fit the map to its bounds (you don't need to actually show the circle on the map if you don't want it).

```
var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value, 10) * 1609.34;
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  center: map.getCenter(),
  radius: radius,
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  map: map
});
```

[live example of a "radius search"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_radiusSearch.html)

[proof of concept fiddle (uses the geocoder to set the map center per the address entered](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j14df3ah/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]
map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());

**code snippet:**

```js
// global "map" variable
var map = null;
var circle = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize() {
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787, -79.359741),
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value, 10) * 1609.34;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      side_bar_html = "";
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var searchCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
      if (circle) circle.setMap(null);
      circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: searchCenter,
        radius: radius,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        map: map
      });
      map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div>
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Toronto">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()"><br>
  <input id="radius" type="textbox" value="50"> miles
</div>
```